# Encrypt followed by decrypt does not return original byte array?

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, keystore, keytool

I have a PrivateKeyEntry entry in my Java KeyStore (.jks) file. I am able to build a `KeyStore` instance from this .jks file as follows:

```
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keystore.load(keystoreFileInputStream, passwordCharArray);
```

I am able to extract `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` instances from `keystore` as follows:

```
PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, passwordCharArray);
PublicKey publicKey = keystore.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey();
```

I encrypt an array of bytes `inputBytes` as follows:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(inputBytes, 0, 128);
```

I do the reverse and decrypt `encryptedBytes` as follows:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(encryptedBytes, 0, 128);
```

However, the bytes in `decryptedBytes` are significantly different from the bytes in `inputBytes`. They should be the same. What have I done wrong?!

If it's important, I created by Java KeyStore file using KeyTool. Specifically, the following command:

```
keytool -genkey -alias my_alias -keyalg RSA -keystore my_keystore.jks -keysize 1024
```

Comment: darijan, it's RSA encryption/decryption, so shouldn't different keys be used for encryption and decryption? Also, I just tried passing in `publicKey` for both operations, and also `privateKey` for both operations, and also `privateKey` for encryption and `publicKey` for decryption, but for each of these I still get a different array to the original...

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that the keys don't make a proper pair. Can you test the key-pair somehow?

Comment: Do you with purpose use the same password both to access the keystore *and* to access the private key?

Comment: jambjo, yes but only because I assigned my key the same password as my keystore on creation (via keytool).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed @Cruncher's suggestion and tried a different Java KeyStore (.jks) file and it looks like it was indeed an issue with the .jks file I was working against rather than the code.

I created a new .jks file using the `keytool -genkey ...` command and encrypting/decrypting using the keys contained with returns the expected results.

Thanks all for the pointers. Appreciate it.